# how can delete a method call such as log.i completely with ASM？

Tags: java, android, gradle

I usually write codes with some log method calls. As you know, it is conveniently to debug.

```
void action(){
    Log.i("TAG","something");
    ...
}
```

I want to use ASM gradle plugin to automatically delete those log method calls  and their parameters.

Of course，I can return null in a `MethodVisitor` when calling the log method. But I don not know how to delete those useless parameters because I can not confirm these code boundary.

Comment: Don't. Most logging frameworks have checks you can do like `isDebugEnabled`. Calling those consistently is enough.

Comment: Why not use logger configuration to turn off logging instead?